# angular material mat-card not displaying latin alphabet characters correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material, latin, mat-card

I am using mat-card in angular material to display some letters of the latin alphabet such as ḍ, ḥ, ṣ, etc. These are all letters with a dot underneath.

Inside a mat-card only, a space is being added after the letter, as in:
aḍ ar (instead of aḍar).

How can I remove this extra space?

Again, this is an issue only inside a mat-card. I really want to use angular material, but with this issue it's a no-no!

Inside my index.html, I declared charset= UTF-8.

anyone has an idea or was faced with the same issue before?

Comment: a minimal stackblitz which replicates this issue would help